# Laravel foreach "Invalid argument supplied for foreach();"

Tags: laravel, foreach

I am using laravel. I create a firewall request as you can see there's ip on the input fields.

The error is on the `edit.blade.php`. when I click submit, it returns this error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

even there are no changes and additional item on the input field. please help me thank you.

```xml
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
    <h5 class="text-truncate col-10 mt-3">
      <span class="fas fa-list-ol icons"></span> <b>Source and Destination</b>
    </h5>
    <hr class="col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11"></hr>
      <div class="row col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-fw-widget" id="tblItems">
          <thead>
            <td class="col-md-1 text-center border-0">
            <td class="col-md-3 col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 border-0 text-center">Source Servername</td>
            <td class="col-md-1 col-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 border-0 text-center">IP address</td>
            <td class="col-md-3 col-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 border-0 text-center">Destination Servername</td>
            <td class="col-md-2 col-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 border-0 text-center">IP address</td>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($fw->fwipmany as $ip)  
              <tr id="{{$ip->fw_dtl_id}}">
                <td class="col-md-1  text-center">
                  <br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ip_id[]" value="{{$ip->fw_dtl_id}}">
                  <label class="form-label" id="row_no"><b>#{{$count}}</b></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                  <!-- <label class="form-label">Item</label> -->
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control text-center" value="{{$ip->fw_src_servername}}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                  <!-- <label class="form-label">Quantity</label> -->
                  <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" min="1" value="{{$ip->fw_src_ip}}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                  <!-- <label class="form-label">UOM/label> -->
                  <input type="name" class="form-control text-center" value="{{$ip->fw_dest_servername}}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                  <!-- <label class="form-label">Description</label> -->
                  <textarea class="form-control text-center" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" readonly>{{ $ip->fw_dest_ip }}</textarea>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @php $count++ @endphp
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="">
          <div class="col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11"></div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```php
$ipcount = 0;
foreach($request->ipadd as $val) {
    if($val != null) {
        $source = FirewallDetail::where('ip_id',$val)->first();
        $source->fw_src_servername  = $request->source_name[$ipcount];
        $source->fw_dest_servername = $request->destname[$ipcount];
        $source->fw_src_ip          = $request->sourceip[$ipcount];
        $source->fw_dest_ip         = $request->destip[$ipcount];
        $source->save();
    } else {
        $ipnew = new FirewallDetail;
        $ipnew->fw_dtl_id          = $fw->fw_number;
        $ipnew->fw_number          = self::IPNumber($fw->fw_number);
        $ipnew->fw_src_servername  = $request->source_name[$ipcount];
        $ipnew->fw_dest_servername = $request->destname[$ipcount];
        $ipnew->fw_src_ip          = $request->sourceip[$ipcount];
        $ipnew->fw_dest_ip         = $request->destip[$ipcount];
        $ipnew->save();
    }
    $ipcount++;
}
```

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $company = Company::all();
    $department = Department::orderBy('orgdep_xname')->get();
    $fw = FirewallRequest::find($id);
    $count = 1;
    $ipdet = FirewallDetail::where('fw_number', $fw->fw_number)->get();
    $serverinstance = FirewallServerInstance::orderby('Server_Instance', 'asc')->get();
    $fileuploads = ChangeManagementUploads::where('fw_number', $fw->fw_number)->get();
    $userEmployment = UserEmployment::where('emp_xuser', Auth::user()->status_xuser)->first();

    session(['message'=>'Request Firewall','icon'=>'bx bx-cart-alt','icon-code'=>'']);

    return view('pages.change_management.cm_firewall.edit', compact(['company', 'fw', 'department', 'serverinstance', 'fileuploads', 'userEmployment', 'ipdet', 'count']));
}
```

Comment: check dd($request->ipadd); in ur controller and check what it contains. also dd($request); to check if 'ipadd' is submitted to controller or not.

Comment: Is there an input element with `name="ipadd"`? I don't see one

Comment: from your form hidden input , I think what you meant to grab is `$request->ip_id` , please correct the `foreach($request->ip_id ... ` and re-test it again .... or cal `dd($request->ip_id)` from inside the controller

Comment: @aqiJaved is a null

Comment: @brombeer i changed to ipdet from the edit controller

Comment: @win it was a null

Comment: inside your controller, check `compact(...)`, you did not send "$ip" , instead you sent "ipdet" , please re-check each of the variables naming you've sent and used

Comment: so I will chaged it to ipdet?